# select option, checkbox, radio tags, if they be empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For textboxes and numbers, If they are empty, We send the following error command very easily:

AJAX

```
    parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text"], input[type="number"]').each(function() {
        if( $(this).val() == "" ) {
            $(this).addClass('input-error');
            next_step = false;
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass('input-error');
        }
    });
```

CSS

```
.input-error {
    border-color: red;
}
```

But for `select option`, `checkbox`, `radio` tags, if they were empty, How should I do?

Comment: you have the `:selected` attribute for selects and `:checked` attribute for checkbox/radios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#mySelectBox').each(function() {
 if($(this).val() == -1)     
        $(this).addClass('input-error');     
 else
        $(this).removeClass('input-error');
});
```

});

A fiddle example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dtqsxn3e/). To clarify a bit, I assumed here that you'd have a "please select option" with the value -1 (so nothing was actually selected):

Answer (score 1):

To verify if a combo box item has been selected, you can check the *selectedIndex* value. 
With the checkbox, you can check its *checked* property.

Working example is at https://jsbin.com/hezemohali/edit?html,js,output

```
function verify() {
  let selectCar = this.document.getElementById("car-brand");
  if(selectCar.selectedIndex === 0)
    selectCar.className = 'input-error';
  else 
    selectCar.classList.remove('input-error');

  let tc = this.document.getElementById("tc");  
  if (!tc.checked)    
    tc.parentNode.className = 'input-error';
  else
    tc.parentNode.classList.remove('input-error');
}
```